# Array answer[i] to if Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

```
int count=0,answer[2,4,3,2,1];
```

The Problem is :`" ']' expected`.

How to solve it i want the first answer with be `answer[0]` the second `answer[1]` and all.

Comment: `int count=0,answer[]={2,4,3,2,1};`

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of `int`s? If so, Google it.

Comment: What is `answer[2,4,3,2,1]` meant to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a regular `int` declaration for an array unless you include brackets in the variable name `answer[]`. Also, array values are defined with curly braces:

```
int count = 0;
int[] answer = {2,4,3,2,1};
```

or

```
int count = 0, answer[] = {2,4,3,2,1};
```

Comment: Note: the first one is far more readable and it should be preferred in all circumstances.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I agree

Comment: Yeah, just clarifying for OP.